# How to map entity to view model? Not string, or bool, or int. Just entity from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following view model:

```
 public class SaveTemplateRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("advertisers")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "AdvertiserNames can not be empty")]
        public List<Advertiser> Advertisers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isActive")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "IsActive field is required")]
        public bool ? IsActive { get; set; }        
    }
```

And look at the signature of the controller where I'm going to use this View Model:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> SaveTemplate([FromBody] SaveTemplateRequest request)
        {
    ...
```

I don't have a problem to map `isActive` from json request. It's simple. But what about `List<Advertiser>` ? Additional, I would like to map it by name! Not by PK id. I will show you the model (Advertiser):

```
public class Advertiser
{
    public int AdvertiserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AdvertiserPushTemplate> AdvertiserPushTemplates { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public string SearchField { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public Advertiser()
    {
        CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Any ideas? How to set up it and where?

Comment: It depending on the content of  your http request. When the standard bindings don't work for you the way to go is implement a custom model binder and fill the model yourself. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0